# Displaying Data From 3 SQL Tables On A Form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I have a program of my own, for my own use, written in Excel VBA & using Access, that I want to rewrite in VB2010 Express using SQLCE.

It currently displays a Form as per the picture attached.

[image: My VBA Form]

What is the best way of replicating something similar ? I know I can create individual Buttons & TextBoxes for each Row, but I am wondering if there is a better way. I tried using DataGridView, but (a) it's pretty ugly & (b) it doesn't let me use more than one Table !!!

I don't mind using a load of individual Buttons & TextBoxes if necessary, but thought I would ask people who might know better, before doing so !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for an alternative to DataGridView, i.e. 3rd party implementations. They should definitely have a more pleasant look, and provide better customization. For example:

- [SourceGrid - Open Source C# Grid Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3531/SourceGrid-Open-Source-C-Grid-Control)

Also check this:

- [DataRepeater control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio//bb735936.aspx).

Both got referenced from here:

- [Is there a better option than DataGridView for repeating WinForms data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496409/is-there-a-better-option-than-datagridview-for-repeating-winforms-data)

Comment: Thanks Neolisk, I think I will go with my own method of multiple buttons & boxes for now, but those links were a great help.